# nodejs TypeError: Cannot read property

Tags: node.js, json, authentication

I have 2 folders, middlewares and routes.
Routes contains a route.js file which has:

```
    const { verifySignUp } = require("../middlewares");
    module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
      "x-access-token, Origin, Content-Type, Accept"
    );
    next();
    });

    app.post(
    "/api/auth/signup",
    [
      verifySignUp.checkDuplicateUsernameOrEmail,
      verifySignUp.checkRolesExisted
    ],
    controller.signup
    );

    app.post("/api/auth/signin", controller.signin);
    };
```

and the verifySignUp.js which contains:

```
    checkDuplicateUsernameOrEmail = (req, res, next) => {...}
```

and when I tried to call the checkDuplicateUsernameOrEmail function, it returned the error

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'checkDuplicateUsernameOrEmail' of undefined`

I dont get it. Where is my wrong doing?

Comment: Sounds like `verifySignUp` is not a property of the export of `middlewares`

Comment: Can you show how you export `verifySignUp` from `middlewares`?

Comment: Is this what you guys mean?
https://imgur.com/a/Earvgqq
Those lines are in verifySignup.js

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem.

The problem is that it's not receiving the body in the 'post' request and the reason for that is that in the `server.js` file you need to put the following code in the top of the content.

```
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
```

With this, it will receive the `body` in the request and it will fix the error above.